# Str.encode() и кириллица

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Объясните, пожалуйста, как именно работает функция перевода строки юникод в байтовую строку.
С переводом строки, составленной из латинских букв, худо-бедно понятно:

```
"Python".encode("utf-8") == b'Python' == b'\x50\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e'
```

Тут каждой букве соответствует один байт, равный номеру этого символа в ASCII или юникоде.
Ничего не понятно в случае перевода строки, составленной из кириллических символов:

```
"Питон".encode("utf-8") == b'\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd'
```

Каждой букве соответствуют уже 2 байта, но откуда они берутся? Насколько я понимаю, это не юникод и не cp1251. В соответствии с какой кодировкой \ стандартом или чем ещё, к примеру, букве "П" соответствуют байты b'\xd0\x9f' и т.д.?
Связано ли всё-таки это представление с таблицей юникода или нет?

Comment: utf-8 кодировка может использовать от 1 до 4 байт  для одного символа (Unicode code point). На каком бы языке вы не кодировали, `П` представлено как два октета D0 9F в utf-8. К Питону это не имеет отношения.

Comment: _Связано ли всё-таки это представление с таблицей юникода или нет?_  Конвертирование в UTF-8 описано в https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. Употребляние в Питон> https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html